# Efficient sampling from a subspace of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: sampling, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have an $N$-dimensional multivariate normal with mean vector and covariance matrix $(\mu,\Omega)$. The covariance matrix is diagonal. Thus one arbitrary draw from this distribution is an $N \times 1$ vector that I will denote by $\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ ... \\ x_N \end{bmatrix}$

I am only interested in draws from this distribution that satisfy a set of linear inequalities. If we define $\mathbf{W}$ (an $N \times N$ matrix) and $\mathbf{L}$ (an $N \times 1$ vector), I am interested in draws such that:
$\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X} \leq \mathbf{L}$ 
where the inequality is evaluated elementwise. In other words I am interested in sampling draws such that every one of these inequalities is satisfied.

One way I could sample from this is to use Cholesky to get draws from the multivariate normal and then using rejection sampling. In my usecase however this is not really feasible as $N$ is large and you end up rejecting almost all samples. **Is there a effective algorithm for efficiently sampling from these kind of subspaces (defined by linear inequalities) of the multivariate normal?**

Comment: The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306784/ discusses a special case of this one.  You might get additional ideas by looking through the hits from [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sample+truncated+normal+multi*+score%3A1).

Comment: Yeah that one is quite closely related. In my case though I am mainly interested in diagonal covariance matrices. So maybe it is easier to find a good algorithm with independent dimensions.

Comment: Assuming diagonality makes no difference, because $\Omega$ can be diagonalized and in so doing $W$ and $L$ will change to a different matrix and vector, but that doesn't change the nature of the problem at all.